# Split Webform Items into two rows

Tags: webforms

i'm working on a problem for a while and still found no answer.
I'm using the Webform Plugin to show a contact form on my site.

The current structure is:

```
<form>
 <div class="form-item">...</div>
 <div class="form-item">...</div>
 <div class="form-item">...</div>
 <div class="form-item">...</div>
</form>
```

Is it possible, maybe with a hook because i want to apply it to a special form, to get this HTML structure:

```
<form>
  <div class="pull-left">
     <div class="form-item">...</div>
     <div class="form-item">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
     <div class="form-item">...</div>
     <div class="form-item">...</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to split the form items into two rows.

Thanks for hints and tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last version of webforms lets you do this outofdabox (put fields in a fieldset though)

You can also achive this using a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) implementation (Have not tested this but i think that should work) and using the [FAPI](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#container) #type container element, for example:

```
$form['left'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array(
      'left',
      drupal_html_class($class_left),
    ),
    'id' => array('lefttoleft'),
  ),
);
```

Create as many container as you want and then move all fields FAPI element inside the container

Comment: Fantastical! :-D